# Spark: Mapgroup and flatten Arrays

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I've a dataset of the following structure

```
| year| id | data            |min_week|max_week||
|2017 | 1  |  [32,21,34]     |       1|       3||
|2017 | 2  | [132, 121, 134] |       1|       3||
|2018 | 1  |  [5, 3, 3,0,1]  |       1|       5||
|2018 | 2  | [15, 13, 13]    |       1|       3||
```

I want the data to be flattened after being sorted by year, something like this

```
| min_year|max_year| id |                    data|min_week|max_week||
|---------+--------+----+------------------------+--------+--------||
|     2017|    2018| 1  |  [32,21,34,5,3,3, 0, 1]|       1|       5||
|     2017|    2018| 2  |  [132,121,134,15,13,13]|       1|       3||
```

I've tried the following, but its not giving what I want

```
case class WeeklyData
  (id: Long,
   min_week: Int,
   max_week: Int,
   data: List[Int],
   year: Int
  )

val data = spark.read.parquet("s3://path")
                    .as[WeeklyData]
                    .groupByKey(k => (k.product_id, k.year))
                    .mapGroups(
                      (k, iter)  => {
                        val s = iter
                          .toList
                          .sortBy(_.year)
                          .flatMap(_.data)
                        s
                      }
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured it out, what I did was grouped by id and year, and passed the function to the grouped data. What I needed was just to group by id and pass the function to it